# What are three ways to access an array element and store it in a register?

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm

I set up a two element array of qwords. I'm trying to figure out three ways I can access the second element and store it in RDX.

I believe I have one way:

```
mydata dq "1,2"


mov   rows,1
mov   col,2
mov   RDX,[mydata, rows, columns *8]
```

Comment: what processor? I'm assuming x86

Comment: http://www.spot.pcc.edu/~ghecht/X86AssyL/ArrayOffsets.pdf

Comment: I was gonna write it out, but that covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you define an array without qoutations:

```
mydaya dq 1, 2
```

And since there is only one row, your row number will be 0.

You can access second data item (column number is 1 and element size is 8) like this:

```
mov   esi, mydata
mov   ebx, 1
mov   RDX, [esi + ebx * 8]
```

or:

```
mov   esi, 1
mov   RDX, [mydata + esi * 8]
```

or:

```
mov   RDX, [mydata + 8]
```

Comment: You should be multiplying by 8 since the element size is 8.